# Travel to India's specific region where classical music and dance events happens

Tags: india, event-based-effects, events, festivals, music

I would like to visit India. I have never been there. As my interests are Indian classical music (Carnatic and Hindustani) and dance (like kathakali), I would like to visit with that theme in mind.

So, I was wondering whether there was a specific festival or event that is available that would focus on this theme, that is a sampling of music in India while traveling around the country.

Comment: What research have you done ? google returns tons of information on music festival in India.

Comment: @JoErNanO India is huge and having cultural & musical differences. So this particular question is viable as for the foreign person It is very hard to get information about that type of region.